# Why am I not able to connect my CoreData in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Disclaimer: I am trying to learn the basics of IOS development, so this question might be very basic.

I'm currently building out my first IOS project, which consists of pulling a random Poem from an API and then giving the user the possibility to save that poem to a "Saved Poem" list. My app currently has a Poem Detail screen (ContentView) and a Home Page screen (where the saved poem list will be).

I've attempted to follow Paul Hudson's tutorial on CoreData (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_Afen3PlDE&ab_channel=PaulHudson). Currently, my goal is to save a poem once the "Bookmark" button on the Detail Screen is tapped. Once a poem saved to CoreData, I would like to display it in a list on the home page.

Code for the Detail View (which includes the Bookmark button)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPoem()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    var currentDate = Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(600), style: .date)

        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack{
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
                        .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .heavy))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    let savedpoem = SavedPoem(context: self.moc)
                    savedpoem.id = UUID()
                    savedpoem.title = "\(poem.title)"
                    savedpoem.author = "\(poem.author)"
                    savedpoem.lines = "\(joined)"
                    
                    try? self.moc.save()
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                        .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .heavy))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    HStack{
                        
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Text("Today's Poem, \(currentDate)")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                .padding(.top, 10)
                            
                            if let poem = fetch.poems.first {
                                
                                let joined = poem.lines.joined(separator: "\n")

                                
                                Text("\(poem.title)")
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                    .lineSpacing(0)
                                
                                Text("BY "+poem.author.uppercased())
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(joined)")
                                        .font(.body)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .padding(.bottom)
                                        .lineSpacing(5)
                                    Spacer()
                                }
      
                                    
                        } else {
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            Button("Get Next Poem") { fetch.getPoem() }
            
        }
        .background(Color.white.ignoresSafeArea())
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
```

Code for the Home Page View

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: SavedPoem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var savedpoems:FetchedResults<SavedPoem>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(savedpoems, id: \.id) { savedpoem in
                    Text(savedpoem.name ?? "Unkown")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

My CoreData Data Model

[image: DataModel]

And finally, my Data Model to pull from the API:

```
import Foundation

struct Poem: Codable, Hashable {
    let title, author: String
    let lines: [String]
    let linecount: String
}

class FetchPoem: ObservableObject {
  // 1.
  @Published var poems = [Poem]()
     
    init() {
        getPoem()
    }
    
    func getPoem() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://poetrydb.org/random/1")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let poemData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Poem].self, from: poemData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.poems = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't build and is throwing me the following errors:

On the Home Page:

```
Cannot find type 'SavedPoem' in scope
Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type
Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred
Missing argument for parameter 'content' in call
```

In Detail View:

`Cannot Find "Poem" in Scope`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding SavedPoem being unknown, try and clean build folder and then rebuild.